# Removing Scatter view item

Tags: wpf, pixelsense, scatterview

If I am using scatter view that contains Library Controls. The user could drag element from the library container to scatter view. After that the user could remove the image.

I created style that contain surface button and image within view box as drag template.

The problem is with the click function of the surface button? what should i write to remove the image.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the whole ScatterViewItem or just the image and keep the button? 
In general you remove ScatterViewItems by finding the Visual Ancestor with this method:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Attempts to get an ancestor of the passed-in element with the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of ancestor to search for.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="descendent">Element whose ancestor to find.</param>
    /// <param name="ancestor">Returned ancestor or null if none found.</param>
    /// <returns>True if found, false otherwise.</returns>
    public static T GetVisualAncestor<T>(DependencyObject descendent) where T : class
    {
        T ancestor = null;
        DependencyObject scan = descendent;
        ancestor = null;

        while (scan != null && ((ancestor = scan as T) == null))
        {
            scan = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(scan);
        }

        return ancestor;
    }
```

then you can remove the SVI from the items collection: ancestor.items.remove(descendent);